# How do I stop spring FilterRegistrationBean from registering my filter on /*

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-filters, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot and I have declared a filter like so:

```
public static class ZeroLeggedOAuthProviderProcessingFilter extends ProtectedResourceProcessingFilter {
    ZeroLeggedOAuthProviderProcessingFilter(LTIConsumerDetailsService ltiConsumerDetailsService, LTIOAuthNonceServices ltioAuthNonceServices, OAuthProcessingFilterEntryPoint oAuthProcessingFilterEntryPoint, OAuthAuthenticationHandler oAuthAuthenticationHandler, OAuthProviderTokenServices oauthProviderTokenServices) {
        super();
        log.info("CONSTRUCT Zero Legged OAuth provider");
        setAuthenticationEntryPoint(oAuthProcessingFilterEntryPoint);
        setAuthHandler(oAuthAuthenticationHandler);
        setConsumerDetailsService(ltiConsumerDetailsService);
        setNonceServices(ltioAuthNonceServices);
        setTokenServices(oauthProviderTokenServices);
        //setIgnoreMissingCredentials(false); // die if OAuth params are not included
    }
}

@Bean(name = "zeroLeggedOAuthProviderProcessingFilter")
public ZeroLeggedOAuthProviderProcessingFilter oauthProviderProcessingFilter() {
    return new ZeroLeggedOAuthProviderProcessingFilter(oauthConsumerDetailsService, oauthNonceServices, oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint(), oauthAuthenticationHandler, oauthProviderTokenServices());
}
```

I apply that filter to a single path like so (which seems to work):

```
@Configuration
@Order(1) // HIGHEST
public static class OAuthSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    ZeroLeggedOAuthProviderProcessingFilter oauthProviderProcessingFilter;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // filters must be ordered: see http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/HttpSecurityBuilder.html#addFilter%28javax.servlet.Filter%29
        http.antMatcher("/oauth/**")
                .addFilterBefore(oauthProviderProcessingFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("OAUTH");
    }
}
```

However, it ends up being applied to all paths and I think it is because of some automatic registration that is happening (based on this in the logs).

> o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter:
>   'zeroLeggedOAuthProviderProcessingFilter' to: [/*]

Is there a way to stop my filter from being automatically registered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving it this way instead (since the FilterRegistrationBean caused other problems).

My filter definition:

```
public static class ZeroLeggedOAuthProviderProcessingFilter extends ProtectedResourceProcessingFilter {
    ZeroLeggedOAuthProviderProcessingFilter(LTIConsumerDetailsService ltiConsumerDetailsService, LTIOAuthNonceServices ltioAuthNonceServices, OAuthProcessingFilterEntryPoint oAuthProcessingFilterEntryPoint, OAuthAuthenticationHandler oAuthAuthenticationHandler, OAuthProviderTokenServices oauthProviderTokenServices) {
        super();
        log.info("CONSTRUCT Zero Legged OAuth provider");
        setAuthenticationEntryPoint(oAuthProcessingFilterEntryPoint);
        setAuthHandler(oAuthAuthenticationHandler);
        setConsumerDetailsService(ltiConsumerDetailsService);
        setNonceServices(ltioAuthNonceServices);
        setTokenServices(oauthProviderTokenServices);
        //setIgnoreMissingCredentials(false); // die if OAuth params are not included
    }
}
```

And my http config which applies that filter to the oauth path only:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1) // HIGHEST
public static class OAuthSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private ZeroLeggedOAuthProviderProcessingFilter zeroLeggedOAuthProviderProcessingFilter;
    @Autowired
    LTIConsumerDetailsService oauthConsumerDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    LTIOAuthNonceServices oauthNonceServices;
    @Autowired
    OAuthAuthenticationHandler oauthAuthenticationHandler;
    @Autowired
    OAuthProcessingFilterEntryPoint oauthProcessingFilterEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    OAuthProviderTokenServices oauthProviderTokenServices;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        zeroLeggedOAuthProviderProcessingFilter = new ZeroLeggedOAuthProviderProcessingFilter(oauthConsumerDetailsService, oauthNonceServices, oauthProcessingFilterEntryPoint, oauthAuthenticationHandler, oauthProviderTokenServices);
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // added filters must be ordered: see http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/HttpSecurityBuilder.html#addFilter%28javax.servlet.Filter%29
        http.antMatcher("/oauth/**")
                .addFilterBefore(zeroLeggedOAuthProviderProcessingFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("OAUTH");
    }
}
```

This also solved another issue I was having where my filter was appearing before the security filters (which caused other issues) so I think this is the best solution. I wish there was some mechanism to tell spring to ignore a filter in the global filters listing as well but this works in the meantime since that does not exist.

Comment: It does exist. The `FilterRegistrationBean` had an "enabled" property. I'm not sure what your problem really was but I bet `FilterRegistrationBean` is the answer.

Comment: But I need the filter to actually work and I want to be able to treat it like a Filter. Unfortunately, the FilterRegistrationBean is not a passthrough for the contained Filter so it doesn't look like a Filter (interface wise) and it doesn't implement any interface. Basically it means the bean for my filter has to become a spring object and I prefer to avoid using spring that way.

Comment: It's not a `Filter` because it's doing a different job. And it *does* implement at least one interface (not that I see the relevance of that). I don't understand why you don't like it, really: Spring controls the lifecycle of `Filters` in a Boot app, so you need a way to expose these features as `@Beans`. Isn't that natural?